# windows service sql connection problems

Tags: sql-server, windows-services

I need your help !!!!

I want to connect to sql server from a windows service, but it throw following exception :

> Login failed for user 'NT
>   AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

My connection string is declared as follow:

```
<add name="CoreConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=10.10.2.102;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;
                       Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I use user name and password instead of Integrated Security=True It works but in final deployment I cannot use user name and password.

What is wrong what can I do????

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you define `Integrated Security=True` in your connection string, whatever user is currently logged in will try to connect to your database. When running this as a console or Winforms app, this is your own user account.

However, if you run it as a Windows NT Service, it's the service account that this service is running under - in your case obviuosly `NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON`.

And the error says it clearly: this user account does not have the permission to connect to the SQL Server.

You have several options:

- stop your NT service and change the service account to be someone who does have access to the SQL Server
- allow the `NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON` to log into your SQL Server and use your database
- create a specific user (e.g. an "application user") in your SQL Server and change your connection string to use that user specifically:

  ```
  connectionString="Data Source=10.10.2.102;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;
                    user id=Your-Application-User-here;password=The-Secret-Password"
  ```

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWER I COULD FIX THE PROBLEM AS BELOW: I changed my service "Log on" to Administrator, so It could connect to the database, thanks for your help.

Comment: @marc_s, what does it really mean to "change the service account"? what steps are actually to be taken?

Comment: @ilanS: Start menu > type "services.msc" and hit enter > find your service > right-click on properties > pick second tab (not sure how it's labelled in your Windows version) which allows you to define under which account this service runs -> set it to whatever makes sense for you

Comment: Hey @marcs, I have other windows service based solutions that run on production, they run on the local system account. I added the NT Authority users to the Logins of the sql server. It seems similar to the other solutions, but it keeps failing. On debug mode it works (when not on win service). So frustrating. Note that the connection seem to work, but the Select is not working: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Customers', database 'MyDB', schema 'dbo'.

Comment: Thanks @marc_s. It seems the nt auth system was disabled. How strange. I used this to solve the problem: `GRANT CONNECT TO [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM]`

Comment: @marc_s could you check for my issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56220598/windows-service-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-system?noredirect=1#comment99063928_56220598

Comment: @marc_s I've changed user Id in my service connection string and I realized it's not watching at it, for example i said UserId = someNotExistingUser and it kept working with 'NT AUTHORITY'..