# Windows Service C# Database connection problems

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, windows-services

I try to make a windows service in C# to send daily automatically emails, based on data read from a specified SQL server database.

I mananged to make the service run, to send email automatically but when I try to insert a `sqlconnection` service just doesn't work anymore. 
Any ideas?

It works if I remove `SqlConnection` and data reader.

Here is my code:

```
    System.Timers.Timer createOrderTimer;
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        createOrderTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        createOrderTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(GetMail);
        createOrderTimer.Interval = 2500;
        createOrderTimer.Enabled = true;
        createOrderTimer.AutoReset = true;
        createOrderTimer.Start();
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }
    public void GetMail(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Server=10.222.160.17,5356;"  
            + "Database=tracking_tool;"
            + "Trusted_Connection=True;"
            + "user=admin;"
            + "password=root");

        string line = "";
        connect.Open();
        SqlCommand GetData = new SqlCommand("select * from validation", connect);
        SqlDataReader ReadData = null;
        ReadData = GetData.ExecuteReader();

        while (ReadData.Read())
        {

            line = ReadData["Line"].ToString();

        }
        connect.Close();

        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.To.Add("daniel.voila@email.com");
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("example@example.com");
        mailMessage.Subject = "example";
        mailMessage.Body = "example";
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("10.214.81.97");
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    }
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: So are you getting any exceptions, this might help a lot investigating the issue. Also are you sure that the connection string is right? There is a comma in the ip. I am no expert but I never encountered this before.

Comment: Trusted_Connection=True obscures the username and password and being you in a service, the user running the service is the one presented to sql server authentication. I would try to remove the Trusted_Connection and use the username and password

Comment: your connection string is weird, @Käsebrot is right. why are you concatenating it? it just makes it harder to read and easier to make mistakes. try something like this: `Data Source=yourserver; Initial Catalog=yourdb; User Id=youruser; Password=yourpword;` and definately remove `trusted connection`

Comment: also, what are you doing with the `line` variable? you just keep replacing its value in the loop. what's the endgame here?

Comment: Probably it is a [duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232375/windows-service-sql-connection-problems?rq=1), but waiting that you explain what is the error message

Comment: That`s the problem, I don`t get any errors. Connection string is ok. And line variable, i just used it for testing, table has only one row.
I tried to put this in a windows form application and everything was ok.

Comment: check the Event Viewer for errors or warnings. services and windows forms apps are not the same btw.

Comment: Checked already. Also debug in Visual Studio, and connection, reader was ok.

Comment: Code that accesses external resources like databases or SMTP servers without proper exception handling or at least error logging is a *bad* idea. Almost as bad is the idea of concatenating connection strings. Use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` instead which is guaranteed to output proper connection strings.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading data from SQL into variable line, but afterwards you don't do anything with it. My guess is, there is actually nothing wrong. How are you determining that something is not working?

Comment: Because there is no email send automatically. If i comment lines where i read data, windows service sends emails. (that reader is just for testing and show you what it`s not working)

Comment: Well, if it doesn't send an email, an exception has occurred. As I don't see any exception handling code, the service should be stopped and you should see an error message in the Windows event log.

Comment: Not necessarily. The mail is sent regardless of the SQL data, this is what I meant with my answer. I think you are getting data back, it's stored in your line and then it continues to sending the mail. Now I understand you're not getting mail, but the problem in that case would be in the sending the mail part, not your db-code. You could insert a breakpoint at the line = Readdata part to see if it's being filled. But like Ted said, you're overwriting it. Eventhough you have only one row in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ConnectionString` is wrong. Try this : (just replace your configs)

```
server={YourSqlInstanceFullName};database={YourDatabaseName};Integrated Security=false;User ID={Database Username};Password={Password}
```