# Windows service - Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication, windows-services, topshelf

I've created simple console log app
which behaves a windows service.

I'm wondering why am I getting an error

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'

if I change my connection string in a way to use some another user which I previously created on SQL Server.

Example of connection string:

```
<value>Data Source=DESKTOP-Z67;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=false;User ID=service;Password=test1234</value>
```

Event if I specified this connection string, I'm getting error

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'

Why isn't there an error like

> Login failed for user 'service'

because I'm using that specific user in the connection string..

PS: I know how to fix this, I can go to SQL Server and edit this user `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` to system admin, but I'm wondering why my app is trying to connect with this user instead of my user from connection string...

Thanks guys

Cheers

Comment: What credentials are you running the service under?

Comment: Are you sure the connection string above is used for your connection?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Indeed its not using a con string from my config file.. how come? If I run it as console app than conn string from my file is used otherwise when I install it as service its using NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.... how come ... ? :O (I've tested it by changing conn string, app crushed but service kept working normaly cuz it obliviously using NT AUTHORITY to log on DB..

Comment: @Alok after I've intalled it I checked properties on a service and it says Log on as : Local System Account.

Comment: Maybe this will help [Windows service installer not reading App.Config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633918/windows-service-installer-not-reading-app-config-file)